# Are these groups isomorphics?

Tags: geometry, symmetry

> Determine the group of symmetry of the pictures, giving a set of
>   generators. Are these groups isomorphics?

[image]

First I determined the group of symmetries, $J=\{I_2,A_{\pi/2},A_\pi,A_{3\pi/2}\}= <A_{\pi/2}>  $
 for the picture in the left side and $G =\{I_2,A_\pi,F_v,F_h\} = <A_\pi,F_v>$ for the picture in the right side where $F_v$ represents a vertical reflection and $F_h$ an horizontal reflection. Then I made a Cayley Table:
[image]

I observed the diagonals are diferents then the groups aren't isomorphics. Is this correct? Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Where did the nice pictures come from?

Comment: @fredgoodman I'm not sure but my teacher maybe made them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is fine.  That the diagonals can't be made to match up indeed shows that the groups are not isomorphic. Another way (really basically the same) is to observe that one group is cyclic of order 4, while in the other group each non-identity element has order 2.

If you haven't done it already, as an exercise show that every group of order 4 is isomorphic to one of these two groups.  (This can likely be found on MSE.)

Comment: Thank you so much fredgoodman. Just two last questions, Can I say the first picture is generated by the group "p411" and the second by the group "p2mm" ?  and  to be sure https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647938/find-all-the-subgroups-of-this-group

Comment: Sorry, this is some sort of special notation that I don't know.  I can't help you with that.

Comment: Anyway thank you so much for your help

Comment: Your use of the crystallographic notation makes me suspect that your teacher/class could have meant your problems to mean something else altogether than what I assumed.  Perhaps you are meant to imagine the pattern of 4 little squares to be repeated infinitely in both directions in the plane, and to determine the "wallpaper" group, which will be an infinite group.

Comment: She gave to us a hint: "It is not a wallpaper obtained by repeating the figure until filling the plane, it's just a simply square" ... so I think the crystallographic notation is not necessary, right??

Comment: OK, good.  I was afraid that I had mislead you.  I think the crystallographic notation is not appropriate.