# Find all the subgroups of this group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I found the following subgroups:
$H_1=\{I_2,A_\pi\}$ $, H_2=\{I_2,F_v\}$ $H_3=\{I_2\ ,F_h\}$ $H_4=\{I_2\}$ $H_5=\{I_2,A_\pi\,F_v,F_h\}$

Is my answer correct? Are there more subgroups?

[image]

Comment: The answer is given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteGroupC2xC2.html). Your group is called the *Kleinian $4$-group*. And yes, these are all subgroups.

Comment: By lagrange's theorem the order of the subgroups must divide the order of the group and all subgroups contain the identity so you have exhausted all possible subgroups.